# JMS template to publish and subscribe to Oracle AQ

Tags: java, oracle, jmstemplate, advanced-queuing

I am trying to connect to Oracle AQ using JMS template to publish and subscribe.
However, I am unable to get it working. I might be lacking basic understanding of connecting to Oracle AQ in general. Any advice would be appreciated

Following is my code

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory;

@EnableJms
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    String url;

    @Bean
    private OracleDataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setURL(url);
        dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws Exception {
        return AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws Exception {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
}
```

Driver class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AQProcessorApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jmsTemplate")
    JmsTemplate template;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AQProcessorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        template.convertAndSend("QUEUE_NAME", "test");
        System.out.println("------------- MESSAGE SENT--------------------------");

    }
```

I get *MESSAGE SENT* in console but I do not see anything in Oracle DB